# The expression must be of class type, but it has type unsigned char*

Tags: c++

I am getting the error "The expression must be of class type, but it has type unsigned char*" in the line "for (int i = 0; i < u.Values.size(); i++)".

What am I doing wrong, and how do I do it correctly?

```
struct udtBinaryFeatures
{
    unsigned char Values[51];
};


wstring bytefeaturestowstring(udtBinaryFeatures &u)
{
    wstring s = L"";

    for (int i = 0; i < u.Values.size(); i++) 
    {
        if (i > 0)
        {
            s += L"-";
        }
        s += unsignedchartowstring(u[i]);
    }
    return s;
}
```

Comment: Arrays do not have methods. There is no `.size()`.

Comment: If the `Values` data member really does have a fixed size then why not declare it as  `std::array<unsigned char, 51> Values;` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because c-style array don't have methods.

You can use instead:
`std::array<usigned char, 51> Values`

Or add `int Size = 51` to your struct and change
`i < u.Values.size();` to `i < u.Size;`